# Getting an error while using redshift boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boto, boto3

```
import boto3

client = boto3.Session(profile_name='Sandbox').client('redshift')
response = client.create_tags(ResourceName='arn:aws:redshift:us-east-1:123456:snapshot:situation',
Tags=[ {'Key': 'k1', 'Value': 'v1'},{'Key': 'k2', 'Value': 'v2'}])
```

Print response

**Error:**

```
File "sai.py", line 5, in <module>
    response = client.create_tags(ResourceName='arn:aws:redshift:us-east-1:123456:snapshot:situation',Tags=[ {'Key': 'k1', 'Value': 'v1'},{'Key': 'k2', 'Value': 'v2'}])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 253, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 543, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateTags operation: The format of the provided snapshot identifier is invalid.
```

Comment: Can you properly format your question?

Comment: Also, reading the error message gives you some clues.

Comment: kaven, can you please check the Tag parameter, It says that I am giving invalid identifier?

but in that create_tag(ResourceName = ''string'', Tags ='' ")
then why it is showing snapshot identifier is invalid ?@kaveh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [appears that](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/redshift-iam-access-control-identity-based.html) the ARN format for an Amazon Redshift snapshot is:

```
arn:aws:redshift:[region]:[account]:snapshot:[cluster-name]/[snapshot-name]
```

Therefore, try using:

```
arn:aws:redshift:us-east-1:123456:snapshot:*/situation
```

Comment: but when i try to generate ARN
arn = self.manager.generate_arn(s['SnapshotIdentifier']) 
I am getting arn:aws:redshift:us-east-1:4712341:snapshot:situation

Comment: That's interesting -- I've never seen `generate_arn()` before. Is there any documentation on this command? Is it part of boto?